# Worklight custom authenticator on native android

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to do a native android authentication against my custom authenticator and login module following the tutorial.

The method called from the main activity was **WLClient.getInstance().login(realm, new MyRequestListener());**

Authentication was successful as per my logs but the following error are thrown;

```
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0020E: Ajax request exception: null [project Bank]
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0117E: Error code: 1, error description: INTERNAL_ERROR, error message: FWLSE0069E: An internal error occurred during gadget request  [project IBMBank]null, User Identity {wl_directUpdateRealm=(name:null, loginModule:WLDirectUpdateNullLoginModule), SubscribeServlet=null, wl_authenticityRealm=null, wl_remoteDisableRealm=(name:null, loginModule:WLRemoteDisableNullLoginModule), SampleAppRealm=null, wl_antiXSRFRealm=(name:acpvfmjdp57ngc1fk18jfr0r5b, loginModule:WLAntiXSRFLoginModule), E2EAuthRealm=(name:pedric, loginModule:E2ELoginModule), wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm=null, WorklightConsole=null, wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm=(name:f3febcd5-51d8-3224-bfb4-a4e34a9d2f4b, loginModule:WLDeviceNoProvisioningLoginModule), myserver=(name:a33004da-6161-45bf-8e91-cab02ed98c85, loginModule:WeakDummy), wl_anonymousUserRealm=(name:a33004da-6161-45bf-8e91-cab02ed98c85, loginModule:WeakDummy)}. [project Bank] 
                                                                                                           com.worklight.common.log.filters.ErrorFilter
```

Please advise on how to troubleshoot this.

I have tested the above custom authenticator and login module in a hybrid application and it works.

Comment: What is your worklight version & build number? Which tutorial are you following (provide a link)? did you try with the sample provided, are you getting the same error?

Answer (score 0):

With the latest sample for MobileFirst Platform Foundation 6.3 and 7.0, I do not get this error in the server, so I suggest to download the latest available sample and try it again.

6.3:  https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/authentication-security/custom-authenticator-login-module/custom-authenticator-login-module-native-android-applications/

7.0:  https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/authentication-security/custom-authenticator-login-module/custom-authenticator-and-login-module-in-native-android-applications/